# Deleting a record with ember-model

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I try to delete a record, a DELETE request is sent to the server but the request seems not correct:

**What is done:**
DELETE
/books
+ body json format

**What I expect:**
DELETE
/books/123
+ no body

1. What is really expected in ember-model ?
2. How can I achieve my expectation (DELETE books/123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it seams clear how ember-model does the [`DELETE` operation](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/blob/master/packages/ember-model/lib/rest_adapter.js#L90):

```
deleteRecord: function(record) {
  var primaryKey = get(record.constructor, 'primaryKey'),
  url = this.buildURL(record.constructor, get(record, primaryKey)),
  self = this;

  return this.ajax(url, record.toJSON(), "DELETE").then(function(data) {
    self.didDeleteRecord(record, data);
  });
}
```

basically the resulting format is: `DELETE /books/123 + JSON body`.
If your backend expects something else then the only way to change it would be to rewrite the `deleteRecord` for your custom needs. But IMO the simplest thing you could do is to just ignore the `JSON body`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tx, it works now. In fact issue was due to my url construction. Is it possible with an option to remove the .json for the get ? My custom RESTAdapter need to do: url=url.replace('.json', '');

Comment: @fvisticot, to separate concerns, would it be possible to post another question with the code of your custom RESTAdapter and I will be glad to help :)